# Storing a printer and a scanner in a damp cellar for 3+ months

Tags: physical-environment

I need to store a printer and a scanner in a damp cellar environment for a couple of months.  Is there a way to package them to protect them from damage?

Comment: What type of printer? laser or inkjet?

Comment: If you have no other choice, and it's limited to a few months, you could protect it by sealing it in an air-tight plastic bag with some desiccant packets.  If you don't have ready access to those, seal the equipment in an air-tight plastic bag with the excess air removed.  Put that inside another air-tight plastic bag, and add a bunch of rice to the outer bag.  If the printer is an inkjet, also check out other answers here on storing an inkjet so the ink doesn't cake the nozzles.

Comment: @fixer1234 This should really be an answer. :)

Comment: Close voters: how is this a question about product, service, or learning material recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

If you have no other choice, and it's limited to a few months, you could protect it by sealing it in an air-tight plastic bag with some desiccant packets.

If you don't have ready access to those, seal the equipment in an air-tight plastic bag with the excess air removed. Put that inside another air-tight plastic bag, and surround it with uncooked rice in the outer bag.  Rice isn't nearly as hygroscopic as the silica used in the desiccant packets, so you will need a lot of it.

If the printer is an inkjet, storing it for months is a problem in any environment because ink will dry up and cake the printhead nozzles. If that applies to you, also check out other answers on Super User and online specifically about that.  How to best deal with that depends a lot on factors, like whether the cartridges contain the printhead; if the printhead is seperate, whether it is easily removed (i.e., a user replaceable part), even the specific make and model of the printer.  So it would be a broad topic to address within this answer.